The math of masser ani distribution in the sources
If masser ani is 10% of one's income and if 10% of the community is poor, then each poor person gets about 100% of a typical person's income.  (For example, in a community of 100 people, if there are 10 poor people, they split the 10% tithe from 90 people or, said another way, they each get the 10% masser ani from 9 people.  So they get 90% of the typical income, with 99 people contributing their 10% tithe to the one poor person.)
If only 1% of the community is poor, each poor person gets some 9.9 times the typical income.
Is the mathematics of masser ani distribution discussed in the sources?

Maaser Ani is 10% of one's remaining produce after first separating Teruma and Maaser Rishon. It is only given in years 3 and 6 of the shmitta cycle

OP appears to mean Maaser Kesafim.   @DoubleAA

@DoubleAA Frequency of giving masser ani is not of much relevance to my question.

@DoubleAA  Lev 27:33 - "very tenth one" - which informs the size of masser ani, as I understand the topic.

@YehudaW I don't understand your source reference https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.27.33 To your question, as a fraction of the total produce grown in the area, Maaser Ani will remain fixed for the local population no matter how the land ownership is distributed (lots of people owning less land or fewer people owning more land). So yes, more poor people in a given area means less per person. Not sure where you're going with this.

@DoubleAA I am just trying to understand the practicalities of masser ani. If the proportion of poor in ancient Israel is similar to the USA today, each poor person would get several times the average annual worth of per capita produce.  Perhaps that would wipe out poverty every 3rd year.

It’s a valid question on paper, but I don’t think it holds up practically. While the poor may end up with more produce, it is doubtful that this would be enough to make the poor man, who may be in debt, homeless, jobless, with a large family, equal to a man who has a field, a house, servants etc. I would be interested to hear an economist’s analysis of what would occur if every poor person was given a lump sum equal to several times the average yearly income.
